# Cufon and german Umlaute (ö,ä,ü)

Tags: javascript, fonts, cufon

I have a strange error with a cufon font. When I have a Umlaut in a word like in "Lösung", the word is displayed like this "LÖSung".

The Font is in Used and the Elements are displayed in the right font.

Here the JS code I use to set the Elements.

```
Cufon.replace('h2,h3,.counter,.blog_more, .navigation a,.contentheading, #search, #footer ',
{font:family:'Lobster 1.3',hover:true });
```

Comment: Please provide a JS Fiddle. Probably the Font just doesn't support all charaters and thus a fall back font is used for the other characters.

Comment: Wow, that strikes me as odd... does it also uppercase the 'S' character, in addition to the 'ö'?

Comment: I hope with JS Fiddle you mean the script. here it is http://www.thomasventurini.com/templates/ravenhom1.7/js/Lobster_13_400.font.js

Comment: jsFiddle is a HTML/CSS/Javascript sandbox to show off code snippets, take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: well, that aint cool, it works in the jsfiddle but not on my site :S http://jsfiddle.net/kmVB8/

Comment: I think i found it, its the css. To disable text-transform:capitalize should do it.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, after playing a bit with the code on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/kmVB8/2/) it turned out that if you have the same problem you have to turn off the 
         text-transform:capitalize;
in your css file

Comment: This appears to be an answer, so please consider clicking the tick symbol, so it is marked as answered. Thanks.